# most uses vs main uses

Tags: word-usage

I wrote:

> **the most uses** of the system includes sharing teaching materials, posting and receiving assignments and grade books.

But I didn't find any similar usage of "the **most** uses" in the Web. However there are millions for "the **main** uses", what is the difference?

Comment: **uses** is plural, thus **include**.  You've used it correctly, and you should be able to find gazillions of similar constructions.   For the sake of parallelism, you might consider adding a verb before "grade books".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your sentence is fine, considering the numerous similar examples rendered [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+main+uses+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThe%20main%20uses%20of%3B%2Cc0).

However, you should use **include** instead of **includes** as the verb should agree with the subject, that is, plural.

And, as TRomano points out in his comment, you also need a verb before **grade books**.

As for your update, the use of **most** is valid either, as **main** and **most** have close meanings.

In your context **most** is a determiner that denotes the greatest amount (majority} of uses whereas **main** indicates the most important, principal or chief uses.

Comment: I did it, @Ahmad.

Answer (score 2):

The terms *main* and *most* are similar in meaning, but they don't behave the same from a grammatical perspective.

For example, when used at the beginning of a sentence the expression *main uses of the system* often takes a definite article:

> **The** main uses of the system include X, Y, and Z.

(This article isn't required, but it is often included.)

On the other hand, the expression *most uses of the system* would ordinarily omit the definite article:

> **Most** uses of the system are safe and don't involve any personal risk.

That said, when used as an object, the superlative *most* often uses a definite article:

> Of all the uses of the system, X is **the** most risky and requires stringent safety precautions.

Comment: Thanks, but you still didn't say why "the most uses" with "the" is incorrect, I think "most" here is a determiner itself and we don't put two determiners beside each other, right?